# Highcharts datagrouping issue

Tags: highcharts

I am facing a strange problem with highcharts(highstock) datagrouping. I want to show grouped data in week or month and at the same time zoom the chart to a specific period (I am using chart.yAxis[0].min = ). When the width of the overall chart is high and when I set the the zoom level to a short period (say a few months), data is not grouped to the period I specify.

Refer to the fiddle link below. I have specified datagrouping as 'month' (`{units:[['month',[1]]], enabled:true}`) and yAxis[0].min as 29 Jul 2010. You will observe that data is not grouped in months.
Now try to reduce the width jsfiddle result panel by dragging the divider. When the size of the result area (or the chart) is reduced, datagrouping starts working.

http://jsfiddle.net/amit657/of1mv8yv/2/

Any idea how can I force datagrouping and at the same zoom the chart to show data for a specific period?

Comment: Actually, when I open your JSFiddle, the data grouping is enabled for me. *Increasing* the width of the result panel by some amount (not just a small amount though) stops the data grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force data grouping set [`forced`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#series<line>.dataGrouping.forced) in `dataGrouping` to `true`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/of1mv8yv/4/

```
...
        dataGrouping: {
            units: [
                ['month', [1]]
            ],
            enabled: true,
            forced: true
        }
...
```